# How to use asp.net core as a backend authenticate with active directory

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using angular2 as a front-end. My Back-end is ASP.NET Core and I am using it as a Restful Web API. How can I authenticate credentials from angular against a local active directory?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of ASP.NET you could implement the ASP.NET Membership or Identity which can connect to AD.

You should easily find various examples of these.

I have recently looked at Auth0, which means you can integrate a variety of ways, front or back-end. 
see: https://auth0.com
(not affiliated)